# Which translation (Russian or English) of The Witcher books is closer to the Polish original?

Tags: translation, the-witcher

I'd like to read Sapkowski's The Witcher book series.

Unfortunately, I can't understand Polish; so can't read the originals.

Fortunately, I am fluently bilingual in English and Russian; so have the luxury of choosing which of the two translations to pick to read.

As someone intimately familiar with challenges and pitfalls of translated fiction works (both as fluently bilingual fan who read a ton of English-to-Russian and Polish-to-Russian fiction translations; and someone who tried to dabble in translation myself - including all of my answers on SFF which were for Russian literature), I know that not all translations are created equal. Russian translations are infamous for being crappy (Harry Potter, Tolkien) or awesome (Lem, Zelazny), while some English translations of Russian works aren't really up to snuff either.

I'd like to choose the translation which is the most faithful, both style and story wise. Quality of the translation as literary work is secondary but not unimportant.

Which one should I choose between English and Russian translations of Sapkowski's *The Witcher* books?

Ideally, the answer would be based on (in order of preference):

- Sapkowski's stated opinion
- Opinion of someone known to be a professional fiction translator fluent in both English and Russian
- Book critic reviews of specific translations as high or low fidelity (compared to original Polish)
- Opinion  - ideally aggregated - of people who are bi/tri lingual in 2 or 3 of English/Russian + Polish.

Comment: FYI, found some criticisms of Russian translations here: http://www.sapkowski.su/modules.php?name=Articles&pa=list_pages_categories&cid=17

Comment: Since many members of the Russian Language stack exchange will already know both Russian and English, it might be a good place to find one who also knows Polish.

Comment: I think your best bet is a Polish person who knows either Russian or English or maybe even both. Maybe ask on some Polish forum?

Comment: I personally enjoyed The Witcher in Russian over English, it felt more authentic with Russian being related to Polish. For example, compare Полуденница and Noonwraith, the former is deep, the latter is somewhat shallow and does not reflect the spirit of the universe in my perception.

Comment: I don't know Russian, but I can tell you the English version, while highly enjoyable, at times reads as if the translator wasn't *completely* fluent in English. Some distracting or ungrammatical wordings, such as for example in *The Lesser Evil* someone telling Geralt "she said to tell you to pick the lesser" (or something like that, not an exact quote but I remember it didn't say "the lesser evil" or "the lesser one", just that: "the lesser").

Comment: @andresf. I interpreted such phrasings an as intentional stylistic choice to give a 'medieval speech' feeling.

Comment: @ukemi maybe! But I doubt it for two reasons: because it reads more modern/clumsy than medieval, and because (I'm told) the Polish original attempts a "modern" feel, so it's likely the English translation attempted to replicate that feel. To be honest I think it's just a bad translation :P